# Corda apps not visible on 10004 port

Tags: blockchain, corda

I'm working on Corda on Azure Cloud.

I have deployed a Corda blockchain (4 nodes, 1 notary and 1 network manager) in Corda 2.0.

I have tried to follow the tutorial https://docs.corda.net/azure-vm.html.

When I go to `http://(public IP address):10004/`, I don't see my Cordapps.

I have 2 installed (jar files in `/opt/corda/plugins`) on each node: `corda-finance` (already installed by Azure) and `yo!app` (version M11)

I see :

```
Installed CorDapps
No installed custom CorDapps.
```

If I go to `http://(public IP address):(port)/web/yo`, I have :

```
Corda O=Organisation 2 (Corda 2.0.0), L=London, C=GB
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /web/yo. Reason:

    Not Found
    Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.7.v20170914
```

Do anyone know why?

Answer (score 3):

I found the problem,
The yo!app version M11 doesn't work for Corda V2. There is nothing in the tutorial saying what to do (I think it is outdated) but I have an updated version of yo!app on https://explore.corda.zone/, you can upload it on your node in the pluging folder with

> wget http://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/cordapp-showcase/yo-4.jar

strangely the "corda-finance.jar" file don't seem to work, either the jar file is also outdated or it is not a "real" cordapps and thus , it doesn't appear on the web-service page.

Hope this can be helpful to someone else.